# What to post in HTTP POST

Tags: java, html, http-post, jsoup, httprequest

I am working on an android app which helps the user login. The site which I want to login is [this](http://erp.mitpune.com/)

I have been now searching for 2 days straight but haven't found myself any answer as to what all I should post.
The problem that I am facing is what all parameters should I post ? I have tried every possible combination of hidden and non-hidden and also tried with cookies.

It would be really kind of you if you could give me the list of the parameters that I should include in my request.

As of now , this is my code

```
Document docl = Jsoup.connect("http://erp.mitpune.com/AdminLogin.aspx")
                                .data("__VIEWSTATE","/wEPDwUINDA4MDU2ODdkZGYVkCI+Zarbu9B42es/RUu7ZNbD")
                                .data("txtPassword","*******")
                .data("__LASTFOCUS","")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET","")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE","/wEPDwUINDA4MDU2ODdkZGYVkCI+Zarbu9B42es/RUu7ZNbD")
                .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR","B8B84CAE")
                .data("hdnMsg","")
                                .data("txtUserId","********")
                .data("btnLogin","Login")

                                .method(Connection.Method.POST).post();
```

I am using jsoup,on android studio, but just the list would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

txtUserId  and txtPassword

posted to Adminlogin.aspx

inside form1

so form1.txtUserId   and form1.txtPassword

Comment: they may be checking for invalid attempts by checking the X-Frame-Options or Host fields, What error do you get when you try to send

Comment: Did you check the function StudentLogin on javascript, it is submitting to ValidateChangePassword.aspx then doing a postback

Comment: I don't get any sort of error ma'am.They just redirect me back to same login page.

Comment: The code on the page looks like there is multiple things, i think you may find that they are returning something - do you get a 200 or do you get any text on the page like "Password was invalid"

Comment: What I am currently getting is this - "179|error|500|The page is performing an async postback but the ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering property is set to false. Ensure that the property is set to true during an async postback.|"

Comment: Thank you for your time ma'am , I got my answer. I was supposed to set a useragent

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick output of data variables by Fiddler Chrome Extension

```
ScriptManager1: UpdatePanel1|btnLogin
__ASYNCPOST: true
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__EVENTTARGET: btnLogin
__LASTFOCUS:
__VIEWSTATE: /wEPDwUINDA4MDU2ODdkZGYVkCI+Zarbu9B42es/RUu7ZNbD
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: B8B84CAE
hdnMsg:
txtPassword: sasasa
txtUserId: jajas
```

Seems like _ASYNCPOST and ScriptManager1 are not in your post variables .

Comment: Thanks Bruv. This really helped me get my answer. You da man!